# WordPress Translate Date Function is giving Error

Tags: date-time

I have a function for translating wordpress date and numbers etc. I am not sure what's wrong with this function. The function works perfectly but wordpress shows error on pages with custom fields while this function is active. Can anyone please update it with latest codex. Thanks.

```
<?php
/**
 * Bangla Date translate class for WordPress
 *
 * Converts English months, dates to equivalent Bangla digits
 * and month names.
 *
 * @author Tareq Hasan <tareq@wedevs.com>
 */
class WP_BanglaDate {
    

    public function __construct() {
        if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        add_filter( 'the_time', array( $this, 'translate' ) );
        add_filter( 'the_date', array( $this, 'translate' ) );

        add_filter( 'get_the_date', array( $this, 'translate' ) );
        add_filter( 'get_the_modified_date', array( $this, 'translate' ) );
        add_filter( 'get_the_time', array( $this, 'translate' ) );
        add_filter( 'date_i18n', array( $this, 'translate' ) );

        add_filter( 'comments_number', array( $this, 'translate' ) );

        add_filter( 'get_comment_date', array( $this, 'translate' ) );
        add_filter( 'get_comment_time', array( $this, 'translate' ) );

        add_filter( 'number_format_i18n', array( $this, 'translate' ) );
        
        add_filter( 'wp_get_object_terms', array( $this, 'translate' ) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main function that handles the string
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @return string
     */
    function translate( $str ) {
        if ( !$str ) {
            return;
        }

        $str = $this->translate_number( $str );
        $str = $this->translate_day( $str );
        $str = $this->translate_am( $str );

        return $str;
    }

    /**
     * Translate numbers only
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @return string
     */
    function translate_number( $str ) {
        $en = array( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );
        $bn = array( '০', '১', '২', '৩', '৪', '৫', '৬', '৭', '৮', '৯' );

        $str = str_replace( $en, $bn, $str );

        return $str;
    }

    /**
     * Translate months only
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @return string
     */
    function translate_day( $str ) {
        $en = array( 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' );
        $en_short = array( 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' );
        $bn = array( 'জানুয়ারী', 'ফেব্রুয়ারী', 'মার্চ', 'এপ্রিল', 'মে', 'জুন', 'জুলাই', 'অগাস্ট', 'সেপ্টেম্বর', 'অক্টোবর', 'নভেম্বর', 'ডিসেম্বর' );

        $str = str_replace( $en, $bn, $str );
        $str = str_replace( $en_short, $bn, $str );

        return $str;
    }

    /**
     * Translate AM and PM
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @return string
     */
    function translate_am( $str ) {
        $en = array( 'am', 'pm' );
        $bn = array( 'পূর্বাহ্ন', 'অপরাহ্ন' );

        $str = str_replace( $en, $bn, $str );

        return $str;
    }
}

$bn = new WP_BanglaDate();



/**
 * This function converts all english number's to bangla number
 */
function make_bangla_number( $str ) {
    $engNumber = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
    $bangNumber = array('১','২','৩','৪','৫','৬','৭','৮','৯','০');
    $converted = str_replace($engNumber, $bangNumber, $str);
 
    return $converted;
}
```

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: Its very unlikely that you would be getting errors for this function from other funcitons. Just make sure, the names of the functions are unique. Especially $bn variable and make_bangla_number()